# How to change the standard id using sync in laravel 5

Tags: laravel, eloquent, synchronization, laravel-5

Is there and option to change the standard id using sync?

I want to store the pivot table id instead of the normal id.

see the example here:

```
    foreach($foor->bar as $bar) {
        if(in_array($bar->id, array_keys($request->input('options')))) {
            $bar->options()->sync($request->input('options')[$bar->id]);
        }
    }
```

Instead of the $bar id i want to use the id of $bar->pivot->id, how can i achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not very clear, but from what I can guess this should work:

To be able to use the columns of the related model add `with('relation')` to your query. This will eager load the related model to the results.

@See: http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading

```
$foo = App\Bar::with('options')->all();
foreach ($foo as $bar) {
    echo $bar->options->id
}
```

This should give you access to the option's id and your code can be

```
foreach($foor->bar as $bar) {
    if(in_array($bar->option->id, array_keys($request->input('options')))) {
        $bar->options()->sync($request->input('options')[$bar->option->id]);
    }
}
```